What benefits do developers prioritize when selecting freelance projects?
As a developer exploring freelance opportunities, I've recently come across the Martian Circle, which offers a range of benefits that seem particularly aligned with what I value. For instance, they emphasize working within the same time zone, which simplifies collaboration, and they handle administrative tasks, allowing me to focus more on development.
Through collaborating with their team, I am now reconsidering what I prioritize in freelancing and I am curious to know, what are some of the key benefits you look for when deciding to take on a freelance project? Are there specific aspects that are crucial to your decision-making process?

Some of my thoughts...

Jobs that I can do quickly (in my sleep practically) that pay good money & which the client believes it's normal for those jobs to take weeks or a month. In this situation you have a lot of flexibility with what you do with your time: lead time, unexpected emergencies, being able to squeeze in other jobs.
Avoid jobs that require NDA unless they pay really, really well. Small jobs with NDA tend to be connected to clients who have unreasonable expectations, hard to satisfy clients, clients that expect you to give them extras for free. It's too much hassle.
Jobs that help me build relationships with quality middlemen because middlemen can bring you a lot more work and quality clients than you can bring yourself.
Don't compete with people who are a lot less taleneted/experienced than yourself. It's a better use of your time to find better clients/jobs.

